# PHP Postgres Query % variable

Tags: php, postgresql

I'm working as replacement of a dev who just went on vacation, and the system is PHP with a Postgres DB.

My problem lies in an specific file which generates a pdf, and the query is this one:

```
 $query=
    "
           SELECT pac_rut,pac_nombres,pac_appat,pac_apmat,date_trunc('second',receta_fecha_emision) as fecha,
           ABS(SUM(stock_cant))as cantidad_despachada FROM pacientes
            INNER JOIN receta on receta_paciente_id=pac_id
            INNER JOIN recetas_detalle on recetad_receta_id=receta_id
            INNER JOIN logs on log_recetad_id=recetad_id
            INNER JOIN stock on stock_log_id=log_id
            WHERE date_trunc('day',receta_fecha_emision) BETWEEN '[%fecha1]' AND '[%fecha2]'
            AND stock_bod_id=4
            AND recetad_art_id=[%cod]
            GROUP BY pacientes.pac_rut,pacientes.pac_nombres,pacientes.pac_appat,
            pacientes.pac_apmat,receta.receta_fecha_emision
            ORDER BY receta_fecha_emision
     ";
```

I've been searching where the [%cod] expression comes from, is it a PHP expression or Postgres?, because i need to use that value outside of the query.

I'll edit further if a more specific point is needed, i'm still try to work through this.

Comment: Looks like those might be replaced in the query by php values. I would check to see if the $query string is updated.